# How to run an Express app locally and connect to a remote Heroku Postgres instance

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, heroku, heroku-postgres

I have an `Express.js` app running in a `Heroku instance` and it connects just fine to the `Heroku PostgreSQL instance` I have connected to it when it is running in the Heroku app itself.

But when I try to run the `Express app` locally while developing and debugging, it cannot connect to the `remote Postgres database`.

This forces me to have to push small changes to the code handling database queries to Heroku and test them there, examine error messages through Heroku CLI, fix the errors locally, and repeat, which is significantly slower than if I was able to do this locally.

I have seen elsewhere that this is often due to SSL being disabled locally,
 so I tried some solutions that people recommended like using Heroku CLI to port forward locally and then using Visual Studio Code to connect to this local version, but I was unable to get this working.

Below is the `launch.json` file I was told to use to connect to the database while debugging in Visual Studio Code:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "attach",
            "name": "Heroku",
            "address": "localhost",
            "port": 9229,
            "protocol": "inspector",
            "localRoot": "${workspaceFolder}\\source\\index.js",
            "remoteRoot": "/app"
        }
    ]
}
```

And below here is the command I was told to use to port forward the Heroku instance locally:

```
heroku ps:forward 9229 -a my-app-name
```

When I try running the command, it says it could not connect to the dyno and to check that its running. When I check, it shows that it is running, just idle, and that my quota for the month is nowhere near full.

Is there a step that I am missing? Or is there a completely different way of connecting to the remote database that is easier than this?

Comment: 1. Are you behind a proxy?

2. Are you mixing HTTPS & HTTP connections?

Your issues may be there.

Comment: @Zardoz I am not behind a proxy. Its possible that I could be mixing HTTP and HTTPS connections though. How would I know?

Comment: Your browser console, or network console should tell you

Comment: @Zardoz the local version is using HTTP but the remote version is using HTTPS. Could that be a problem?

Comment: Yes it could be.